# How to work with view subcontainers in Flow

Tags: android, square-flow

what is the intended way to tackle subcontainer navigation with `Flow` on Android.

Let's say I have a couple of `Screens` where one works like a container screen itself - there I want to do some subnavigation (changing part of this screen).

I guess the Screen should serve as a temporal `Flow.Dispatcher` and proxy all `Flow` commands. How to do that? By calling `Flow.setDispatcher` I effectively replace the parent dispatcher, which is not intended. 
I guess creating a new `Flow` instance is not welcomed either, that should be an app wide singleton..?

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of scenario that https://github.com/square/flow/tree/master/flow-path was made for.

Life is best if you have a single app-wide instance of flow. We've tried it the other way, where a higher level flow has a screen that happens to be a container for a nested flow, and life gets pretty complicated pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I actually started having issues with my nested Flows too, so I rather started digging into how to somehow switch (or nest - that seems to be the way) containers to allow different subview structure, animations,..
And I'm already using these decoupled versions of flow+flow-path libraries. Still getting lost.
Let's imagine one scenario related to flow-sample app.
I have first Path as a fullscreen view. Then I have next one that serves rather as a masterdetail wrapper for another bunch of Paths. Is there any intended way how to do that? Or is it subject to my imagination:)

Comment: Hey @rjrjr, any plans to make a similar sample available again?